# AutoIncrement non-primary key or Make unique composite key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, computed-column, composite-types

I have a db with a table that has a rollover value such as OrderNumber and another column is year.

This is the primary key - a composite key - but there are other tables with which I need to use a foreign key relationship - I really would prefer to have an auto increment surrogate key for this table, the trick though is that OrderNumber and Year must be unique. IS there a good way to handle this?

I was reading here for some inspirations. [Composite field in SQL Server, does it exist?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41024/composite-field-in-sql-server-does-it-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Vérace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34007/v%C3%A9race) suggested, you can do both: create a surrogate (auto-increment) key to simplify joins and related table structures, and add a unique constraint on the two current PK columns to continue to enforce the proper data integrity.

In SQL Server, multiple columns can participate in a unique index / constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Orders
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Year_OrderNumber
UNIQUE ([Year], OrderNumber);
```

Thus there is no need to create a computed column to combine the two columns.